# Installing caffe on ubuntu 15.04 with anaconda 3 for python 3.4 - no module caffe found

Tags: python, ubuntu, anaconda, caffe

I am trying to install caffe on my ubuntu 15.04 with anaconda 3 (for python 3.4). I managed to install all requirements and I followed the instructions from official website. So I downloaded caffe-master and did:

```
cd ./caffe-master
make all
make pycaffe
```

It completes fine, no errors (finally).
But after that if I go into anaconda and do

```
import caffe
```

I get no module caffe is found. What am I doing wrong? Any ideas?

Comment: Do you have multiple versions of Python installed?

Comment: Did you `$PYTHONPATH by export PYTHONPATH=/path/to/caffe/python:$PYTHONPATH `?

Comment: Just anaconda, but yes, 2 versions. But in make.config I included path to anaconda's Python 3.4 only

Comment: Which path is the path to caffe? It will be within the folder within I run make all?

Comment: You probably need to configure caffe to install to the Anaconda Python when you compile it.

Comment: @asmeurer but I believe I already did it. In make.config there is a special line for anaconda path and I provided a path to my anaconda.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally solved. Honestly the issue was in incorrect makefile.config. I needed to be extremely careful in adjusting it to specify all path to anaconda folders - I have incorrectly specified the path to python3.4 libraries.

The point is - when set up caffe with anaconda and facing issues you need to go over makefile.config one more time - you should have misconfigured something

Comment: I am having some troubles too with anaconda and python 3.5 Woud you be so kind an post your makefile?

Answer (score 1):

you can try these steps:

To use caffe within python, export its path as

export PYTHONPATH=~/Home/*username*/caffe/python:$PYTHONPATH

Replace username  with the your username in the system.

Once you've done this, run the python terminal and import caffe

> > > import caffe

If it throws a 'module not found' error, check if it has been appended in pythonpath properly by typing

> > > import sys
> > >       sys.path
> > >       ['', '/home/nikita/caffe/python', '/home/nikita', '/usr/lib/python2.7', '/usr/lib/python2.7/plat-x86_64-linux-gnu', '/usr/lib
> > >       /python2.7/lib-tk', '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-old', '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload', '/home/nikita/.local/lib/python2.7/site-
> > >       packages']

If you see that the /home/username /caffe/python path, isn't there, then do

> > > sys.path.append('/Home/username/caffe/python')